# How to remove previous div if next div is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have next structure:

```
<div class="holder">

  <div class="item">
    <img class="popup_btn">
    <div class="popup_text>sometext_here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img class="popup_btn">
    <div class="popup_text>sometext_here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img class="popup_btn">
    <div class="popup_text>sometext_here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img class="popup_btn">
    <div class="popup_text></div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img class="popup_btn">
    <div class="popup_text></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

How do I remove images with class "popup_btn" if element next to them with class "popup_text" has no content inside?

Comment: There is no `<div />` with class `popup_btn`

Comment: `popup_btn` is on the `img` elements, do you mean the containing `.item` div instead?

Comment: Post a code attempt to make a valid question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:empty` selector to retrieve elements with no contents. From there you can traverse the DOM to `remove()` the required elements. Try this:

```
$('.popup_text:empty').prev('.popup_btn').remove();
```

Or alternatively, assuming you want to remove the `.item` container:

```
$('.popup_text:empty').closest('.item').remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqxpbdfg/)

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
$("div.popup_text").each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.text() === "") {
        $el.siblings(".popup_btn").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no code attempt and no indication that he tried anything.

Comment: @Kriggs then it's best to guide the question asker about standard SO practice via a comment on the question, but it's still acceptable to answer the question if you can.

Answer (score 0):

First off -- your markup is wrong, you're missing the closing quote `"` around many of your class names.

Here is some vanilla javaScript to do what you want, no libraries required.

```
// select all the .item classes
var items = document.querySelectorAll('div.item');

// loop through them
for ( var i=0; i<items.length; i++ ) {
  // store the contents into variables
  var popup_text = items[i].querySelector('.popup_text'),
      popup_btn = items[i].querySelector('.popup_btn');

  // if the text length is 0, it's empty. remove the button img.
  if (popup_text.textContent.length === 0) {
    popup_btn.remove();
  }
}
```

example: http://jsbin.com/logaximoke/edit?html,js,output

There are more concise options you can use, but I feel this one is easy for a beginner to understand and wrap their mind around.